# ¿Cómo actualizar una columna en cascada en phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de actualizar los valores de la columna kilometraje, pero los siguientes registros también tienen que ser modificados sumándole el valor de kilometraje + el ultimo recorrido.
[image: Ejemplo de historial de kilometraje incorrecto]

En el la imagen el kilometraje incorrecto es 598817 y tengo que cambiarlo, pero tengo que actualizar los siguientes registros y volver a calcular el kilometraje sumando el kilometraje del registro anterior + el kilometraje del ultimo recorrido del registro actual.

Hay forma de hacer esto con un query o se debe realizar de otra forma

Comment: ¿Quieres mantener una especie de acumulador en la tabla? ¿Hay algo que justifique eso?

Comment: En este caso es para corregir los registros de forma automática sin tener que modificar de uno por uno los registros, ya que en el ejemplo solo son los datos de un recorrido, en la BD hay mas de 100 mil registros que como este deben ser corregidos

Comment: Mi pregunta es por qué hay que hacer eso en la base de datos ¿? La base de datos no es para eso, a no ser que el contexto lo justifique por una razón muy concreta.

Comment: Tienes razón no es correcto que en la BD se realice este tipo de acciones pero en este caso diría que en este caso es por una emergencia para después poder ir a reparar el código de php que deberia hacerlo

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563918/5587982) hay varias respuestas que hacen lo que quieres.